# Como incorporar um mapa personalizado no Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

Tenho um mapa personalizado feito no Google maps e quero incorporar ele em um app Android. Quero que assim que entrar no app já carregue o mapa personalizado.

Comment: Seu estilo está em um json?

Comment: Não, está em um mapa do Google My Maps, é um mapa editável em tempo real, consegui puxar via frame e utilizar em um webview, só queria saber se tem outra forma utilizando a api Google maps, mas acho que não.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode personalizar o estilo do seu mapa usando `MapStyleOptions` através de um objeto JSON no qual você pode colocar dentro do diretório `raw`. Isso é definido dentro do método `onMapReady()` em sua *activity*. Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    // Personalizando usando um objeto JSON
    MapStyleOptions style = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
            this, R.raw.style_json);
    googleMap.setMapStyle(style);
}
```

Para mais detalhes você pode conferir na documentação em [como adicionar um mapa estilizado](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling).

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]